# Riemann Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

In the book "Theory and Application of Infinite Series" by [Knopp](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/analysis_real/Infinite_Series-Knopp.pdf), the Riemann theorem for rearrangements of infinite products is cited on p.227, but not proven, i.e.

Let $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$ an infinite product which does not converge absolutely, no factor is zero of this product and $s\in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary.

1. There exist a rearrangement so that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{\sigma(n)})=s$.
2. There exist a rearrangement so that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{\sigma(n)})=+\infty$ or $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{\sigma(n)})=-\infty$.

I am really struggling with the proof. Can someone provide it?

Comment: if $1+a_n > 0$ for all $n$, then you can never get $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{\sigma(n)})$ negative.  If the infinite product converges conditionally, then at most finitely many $1+a_n$ are negative, so you can determine the sign from that (allowing divergence to $0$ or $\pm \infty$.)

Comment: @GEdgar it only says in the book $1+a_n\neq 0$ for all $n$. But this does not forbid $1+a_n <0$. Can you please explain a bit more, why there only exist finitly many $1+a_n<0$ if the product converges conditionally? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, from your link...
[image]
Note the part about "same sign".

To prove it, we can remove the finitely many negative factors, then apply the series theorem to the logarithms of the remaining factors.

Comment: Thank you! But can you please explain shortly, why there only exist finitly many $1+a_n<0$ if the product converges conditionally? That would solve my question!

Comment: If the product converges (conditionally or unconditionally), then $1+a_n \to 1$, so $1+a_n > 0$ except possibly for finitely many $n$.

Comment: You mean $1+a_n<0$ for finitely many $n$ right? Because we would like to exclude these factors.

Comment: Yes: "$1+a_n > 0$ except for finitely many $n$" means "$1+a_n < 0$ for finitely many $n$" (because zero factors are not allowed).

Comment: What does it mean „provided that they have the same sign as the value of the given product“? Which assumption must the factors fulfill?

Comment: If the product is positive, then $\kappa$ and $\mu$ must be positive.  If the product is negative, then $\kappa$ and $\mu$ must be negative.